# Retrieving a specific state in corda

Tags: blockchain, corda

In My Corda project, I need to retrieve a specific state based on the some specific field of the state class, which I have set Unique for each state. How to do that in Corda? The implementation of state is as follows:

```
@BelongsToContract(OfferContract.class)
public class OfferState implements LinearState {
    private final UniqueIdentifier linearID;
    private AnonymousParty sender;
    private AnonymousParty receiver;
    private final String policyID;
    private final double faceValue;
    private double offeredAmount;

    private boolean isActive;

    public OfferState(UniqueIdentifier linearID, AnonymousParty sender, AnonymousParty receiver, String policyID, double faceValue, double offeredAmount, boolean isActive) {
        this.linearID = linearID;
        this.sender = sender;
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.policyID = policyID;
        this.faceValue = faceValue;
        this.offeredAmount = offeredAmount;
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

    public UniqueIdentifier getLinearID() {
        return linearID;
    }

    public AnonymousParty getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public AnonymousParty getReceiver() {
        return receiver;
    }

    public String getPolicyID() {
        return policyID;
    }

    public double getFaceValue() {
        return faceValue;
    }

    public double getOfferedAmount() {
        return offeredAmount;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public UniqueIdentifier getLinearId() {
        return linearID;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public List<AbstractParty> getParticipants() {
        return Arrays.asList(sender,receiver);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString();
    }
}
```

I am querying in the API with the following code But, that is showing empty brackets like [] in the postman output.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getOfferWithID",headers = "Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    private List<StateAndRef<OfferState>> getOfferWithID(HttpServletRequest request) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        String s  = request.getParameter("PolicyID");
        return proxy.vaultQuery(OfferState.class).getStates().stream().filter(it->it.getState().getData().getPolicyID().equalsIgnoreCase(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Can you please tell me, How can I filter states while querying, What is going wrong here?
is there any direct query method so that I can filter it in rpc call itself or Do I really need to wirte a flow for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to query your state by one of its attributes, you must:

- Create a custom schema for your state, see [here](https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Basic/cordapp-example/contracts-java/src/main/java/com/example/schema) and [here](https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/8977a33471a79c2006e2711c285383d96cede659/Basic/cordapp-example/contracts-java/src/main/java/com/example/state/IOUState.java#L53-L67) for examples.
- Use `VaultCustomQueryCriteria` to query against your attribute `policyId`. Read about `VaultCustomQueryCriteria` [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.6/api-vault-query.html) (search for that term, and look for sample code).

Your current approach (using `.filter(it->it.getState().getData().getPolicyID().equalsIgnoreCase(s))`) is very bad, essentially you are bringing a list of all of your states then filtering that list.
What are you going to do when your query returns 1000,000 states?! You are creating a list of 1000,000 entries then looping through that list to find that one record that has your `policyId`!!! This will simply drain your Java Heap, slow your application, and crash it.

Always delegate the search/query to the database by constructing the query in Corda then running it in the DB (using the approach that I already outlined), what you're currently doing is crafting a `select * from some_table` then looping through all of the results, my approach crafts `select * from some_table where policyId = xxx`, which will return one row.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine at the 1st look, not sure what's going wrong. Perhaps there might be something wrong with the `linearId` being passed to the query criteria.

As a reference you could look at the below code which works fine:

https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Advanced/auction-cordapp/workflows/src/main/java/net/corda/samples/flows/AuctionDvPFlow.java#L68

Comment: He wants to query by `policyId` not `linearId`; thus, he needs a custom schema.

Comment: Also his approach of getting all states in a list, then filtering that list is bad.